# Two-Phase-Locking (2PL) Transactions

Tags: database, transactions

I'm currently dealing with the [2-Phase-Lock Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_locking) considering the following schedule S:

`S = R_3 D R_1 A W_2 A W_2 C R_3 B W_3 B R_1 B`

Where R = Read, W = Write, {A, B, C} = objects and {1,2,3} = transactions. 
Now I shall show that the `2PL` can't be used for `S`. But I actually don't see why, I would set the `Locks(L)/Unlocks(U)` like:

`L_3 D R_3 D U_3 D L_1 A R_1 A U_1 A L_2 C W_2 C U_2 C L_3 B R_3 B W_3 B U_3 B R_1 B`

So, I used at maximum 1 `L/U` per Object of a Transaction. What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out why I was wrong. It is correct that a transaction can perform at maximum 1 `Lock/Unlock` per object. But I was forgetting that after a transactions performed its first `Unlock` (doesn't matter on which object) it is not allowed to perform a `Lock` again at all, even on another object that has not been locked before.